# Invalid Character in Base-64 String” using ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, enterprise-library

I have a Sql Server 2008 R2 connection string that looks like

```
  <add name="DBConnectionString"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
connectionString="Data Source=AYZ;Initial Catalog=AYZ;User ID=AYZ;Password=AYZ;"/>
```

When trying to create a new instance of SQLDatabase using EnterpriseLibrary.Data I get the above error.

```
connString =ConnectionStrings.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"];
Database objDB = new SqlDatabase(connString);
```

The detailed exception is as follows :

```
System.FormatException was unhandled by user code
  Message=Invalid character in a Base-64 string.
  Source=mscorlib
  StackTrace:
       at System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s)
       at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.DecryptConnectionString(String strEncyptConStr)
       at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database..ctor(String connectionString, DbProviderFactory dbProviderFactory)
       at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Sql.SqlDatabase..ctor(String connectionString)
       at Syntel.GRC.DAL.CommonDAL..ctor() in D:\Vrushal\Projects\Right Price\Syntel.GRC\Syntel.GRC\Syntel.GRC.DAL\CommonDAL.cs:line 31
       at Syntel.GRC.BLL.CommonBLL..ctor() in D:\Vrushal\Projects\Right Price\Syntel.GRC\Syntel.GRC\Syntel.GRC.BLL\CommonBLL.cs:line 14
       at Global.Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\Vrushal\Projects\Right Price\Syntel.GRC\Syntel.GRC\Syntel.GRC.WEB\App_Code\Global.asax.cs:line 60
       at System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.Web.HttpApplication.RaiseOnError()
  InnerException:
```

Please help me with a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a stack trace to go with this? I can't see why that would be trying to do anything with Base64 offhand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The connection string had to encryted to work. The team working on the project used base64encode.org to encode the string.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `"` at the end of the connection string property. It should be:

```
<add name="ConnectionStringName"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
    connectionString="Data Source=ServerName\InstanceName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;"/>
```

Comment: @zen: and what does that mean exactly? Are you getting an exception? If so update your question with the exception.